# Fastest way to retrieve tabulated data from /res/raw/ and store it into a 2D array on Android

Tags: java, android, csv, file-io, multidimensional-array

I'm working on my first android app, so feel free to point out if I'm doing things incorrectly or suggest another way of doing things.

I have a large file "table". Now, I can store the data as a csv like so

```
a, "stuff with , commas"
b, "foo bar"
c, "test,"
```

or as xml like so

```
<row>
    <number>a</number>
    <equipment>"stuff with , commas"</equipment>
</row>
<row>
    <number>b</number>
    <equipment>"foo bar"</equipment>
</row>
<row>
    <number>c</number>
    <equipment>"test"</equipment>
</row>
```

I'll use whichever I can retrieve and store faster. However, I don't want to hardcode the data.

I need to read the data from `/res/raw/table.csv` or `/res/raw/table.xml` and store it into a list of lists, an array of lists, or an array of arrays, again, I'll use whichever is fastest.

I've tried a couple things:

```
    InputStream equipmentCSV =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.equipment);
    String equipmentString = readTextFile(equipmentCSV);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> equipmentTable = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(equipmentString);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String [] splitLines = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        ArrayList <String> splitLinesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitLines));
        equipmentTable.add(splitLinesList);
    }
```

Where readTextFile is

```
  public String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return outputStream.toString();
    }
```

This took too long, so thinking Scanner might be too slow and lists might take longer than arrays I tried:

```
    String[] lines = equipmentString.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    String [][] equipmentTable = new String[lines.length][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length ; i++){
        String [] splitLines = lines[i].split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        equipmentTable[i][0] = splitLines[0];
        equipmentTable[i][1] = splitLines[1];
    }
```

Which also took too long.

What's a better method of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define `too long` how big is your file?

Comment: regex are not particularly fast. you could make it slightly faster by compiling it once instead of creating it anew for each iteration. You don't need to read the whole file first, you can use a Scanner directly on a file input stream.

Comment: faster than csv would be fixed-length fields, though.

Comment: The file is 558KB. Using the above code it takes about 6 seconds to load it all into memory. Using openCSV it takes about 3. A faster method would be welcomed.

Comment: the fastest way would be to use DataInputStream (and DataOutputStream from a java program to create the file), but the bottleneck could also be from the file reading itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way to do it using openCSV like EagleEye recommended.

```
    List<String []> equipmentList = new ArrayList< String [] >();

    try {
        // where your file in /res/raw/equipment.csv
        InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.equipment);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            equipmentList.add(nextLine);
        }
    } catch(IOException ie){
        // deal with exception
    }

    // if you want to convert it to a 2d array from an arraylist of arrays
    String[][] equipmentTable = (String[][])equipmentList.toArray();
```

To add a library in Android Studio, you can download the jar file here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/

And then add it to your libs folder which should be in the same directory as your build in and src folders.

Then in your `build.gradle` file under `dependencies` add the line `compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')` like so

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    // whatever other dependencies ...
    compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar') // add this line for your jar file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer following links. They should help you.

https://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

These libraries will take care of reading and writing from and to CSV.

For XML refer following link.

http://simple.sourceforge.net/

It has very good documentation too.